# In scipy classification models (such as the svm.svc), how can one get a list of the names for all classes?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, svm

In scipy classification models (such as the svm.svc), how can one get a list of the names for all classes the model may classify points into?

Comment: `scipy` (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/) doesn't have classification models.  I suspect you mean `scikit-learn` (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

For [svm.SVC](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) (and many other models, like LogisticRegression etc.) there is an attribute `classes_` thus on trained model `clf` you can do

```
print clf.classes_
```